# JavaScript JQuery Why buttons' ID are not being correctly referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, web

Hello and thank you for your time.

I have one doubt because I am trying to associate the ID I am reading from the Firebase database to the ID which identifies the button. It is important because of this button leads us to the event's modify page so then the event's ID is the one we use to load its data.

However those buttons' IDs look like they are one position forward let's see:

[image: button's IDs]

As you can see button 0 has ID Ejemplo nuevo which is the following row's event and so on.

Events:
[image: events]

Code:
[image: code]

Function's code:

```
   function insertPlans() {
        setReferences();
        $("#title").html("Planes");
        resetAllData();

        $("#table thead").html("<tr>" +
            "<td>ID</td> <td>Capacidad</td> <td>Fecha</td> <td>Descripción</td> <td>Ubicación</td> " +
            "<td>Título</td> <td>Organizador</td> <td>Precio</td> <td>Prioridad</td><td>Asistentes</td>" +
            "<td>Visibilidad</td></tr>");

        dbRef.child('plans').once('value', function (snap) {
            snap.forEach(function (planID) {
                dbRef.child('plans/' + planID.key.toString()).once('value', function (snap) {
                    var row = "<tr><td><button id='new-button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='saveEventName(this.id)'>Modificar evento</button>" + planID.key.toString() + "</td>";
                    $("#new-button").attr('id', planID.key.toString());
                    snap.forEach(function (fields) {
                        row += "<td>" + fields.val() + "</td>";
                    });
                    $("#table").find("tbody").append(row + "</tr>");
                });
                $("#table").find("tbody").append("</tr>");
            });
        });
    }
```

Also if I do a console log as:

[image: console log]

It prints the correct IDs:

[image: perfect IDss]

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(‘#new-button’) is always referencing the previous row because we haven’t attached the `row` to the document yet.

You can first insert `row` then you can use the selector to change its id

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help digitil. As you said I was editing the previous row because of the current one was not been added to the document.

The solution:

```
function insertPlans() {
        setReferences();
        $("#title").html("Planes");
        resetAllData();

        $("#table thead").html("<tr>" +
            "<td>ID</td> <td>Capacidad</td> <td>Fecha</td> <td>Descripción</td> <td>Ubicación</td> " +
            "<td>Título</td> <td>Organizador</td> <td>Precio</td> <td>Prioridad</td><td>Asistentes</td>" +
            "<td>Visibilidad</td></tr>");

        dbRef.child('plans').once('value', function (snap) {
            snap.forEach(function (planID) {
                dbRef.child('plans/' + planID.key.toString()).once('value', function (snap) {
                    var row = "<tr><td><button id='new-button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='saveEventName(this.id)'>Modificar evento</button>" + planID.key.toString() + "</td>";
                    snap.forEach(function (fields) {
                        row += "<td>" + fields.val() + "</td>";
                    });
                    $("#table").find("tbody").append(row + "</tr>");
                    $("#new-button").attr('id', planID.key.toString());
                });
                $("#table").find("tbody").append("</tr>");
            });
        });
    }
```